# DNS Record data coming up as DnsServerResourceRecordA

Tags: powershell, dns

If I run the command

```
 $alldns = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -computername dns-server -ZoneName "domain.com" -RRType "A"
```

It comes out perfect, showing the ip address :

```
pc2 A     1          10/24/2017 6:00:0... 00:20:00        192.168.1.149
Gaming               A          1          10/24/2017 6:00:0... 00:20:00        192.168.1.139
dc                    A          1          0                    01:00:00        192.168.1.50
dc2                   A          1          0                    01:00:00        192.168.1.51
Surface               A          1          10/24/2017 8:00:0... 00:20:00        192.168.1.141
server1                      A          1          10/19/2017 7:00:0... 00:20:00        192.168.1.200
```

But if I run the additional command

```
$alldns = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -computername dns-server -ZoneName "domain.com" -RRType "A" | Select-Object -Property Hostname, RecordData, Timestamp
```

I get this as a result and the ip goes away, and is replaced with DnsServerResourceRecordA .  Please advise.

```
pc2        DnsServerResourceRecordA   10/24/2017 6:00:00 PM
Gaming     DnsServerResourceRecordA   10/24/2017 6:00:00 PM
dc         DnsServerResourceRecordA
dc2        DnsServerResourceRecordA
Surface    DnsServerResourceRecordA   10/24/2017 8:00:00 PM
server1    DnsServerResourceRecordA   10/19/2017 7:00:00 PM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by extracting  `calculated property` for `IPv4Address`. In select-object, you can use `@{Name='RecordData';Expression={$_.RecordData.IPv4Address}}` instead of just `"RecordData"` in the following manner

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -computername dns-server -ZoneName "domain.com" -RRType "A" | select-object -Property Hostname,Timestamp, @{Name='RecordData';Expression={$_.RecordData.IPv4Address}}
```

More details regarding `calculated property` : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

**Or else**

`Recorddata` can be extracted using `ExpandProperty` . You have to use `-ExpandProperty` in you select-object and the rest (Hostname,Timestamp) can be extracted using `-Property` . You will get `IPv4Address` field using below.

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -computername dns-server -ZoneName "domain.com" -RRType "A" | select-object -ExpandProperty recorddata -Property Hostname,Timestamp
```

More about `expandproperty` :https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vishinde/2012/08/27/expandproperty-in-select-object/

Either way you can replace `DnsServerResourceRecordA` with proper ip address..

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Ara !  Works perfectly.

Comment: modified the answer with alternative method. !